# Reusing connections for Improving performance

Tags: java, network-programming, httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection to make GET requests. Below is the code:

```
class ConnectClass  {
        private HttpURLConnection connection;

        public makerequest(URL url)  throws Exception {
        try {
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            ..... 
            } finally {
             connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
}
```

Is it a good idea to create connection and close it everytime for each request? How can I improve latency? Is it possible to reuse the existing connection without creating a new one everytime.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend for you to search with terms "java keep-alive"

Comment: You don't have any choice. There is no other way to use `Http[s]URLConnection`. The good news is that it does connection pooling itself behind the scenes. But don't call `disconnect()`. Just close the input stream.